# Angular attribute expression not evaluating inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why does the link evaluate the expression inside the directive using the link attribute, but the template does not? Note that I'm only using 'link' here for console.log illustrative purposes.

My end goal is to have data passed into a directive via its attribute and have that data render as its template.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <my-directive text="{{data}}" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module("myApp", []).directive("myDirective", function () {
  return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
          text: "@text",
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log(attrs.text);
      },
      template: function(element, attrs){
        console.log(attrs.text);
      }
  };
}).controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.data = 'test';
});
```

output:

```
{{data}}
test
```

Comment: So are you trying to use the `text` attribute to specify what the contents of the directive are?

Comment: @GregL Yes, if by "contents of the directive" you mean a template. I want to be able to directly use in my template what is passed in through the html attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe that you are confusing the two scopes you are dealing with here. By using an isolate scope like you have here, you are copying the *interpolated value* of the `text` attribute (evaluated against the scope at the point the directive is encountered (the controller scope in your example)) to a property on the isolate scope called 'text'. So within your directive's template, you should be referring to `text` to access that value ("test" in your case).

However, based on your comment, you really do want to be able to pass in the markup for the directive to display, as if it were running against the controller's scope. This is what *transclusion* is for - the transcluded content will be placed where you indicate inside the directive template and evaluated against the controller's scope, so `{{data}}` will correctly resolve to `test`.

In that case, your markup would become:

```
<my-directive>{{data}}</my-directive>
```

And your JS becomes:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      // no need for scope bindings here
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // nothing to do here for now
    },
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
  };
}).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = 'test';
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d0oMoi0uWsb2AMmbrsOV)

Comment: Actually Greg, the first thing you described sounds more similar to what I was trying to do! I want to take data from the controller accessible from the point where the directive is used, pass that data in through the directives attribute, use that data inside the directive, and return a template that uses the passed in data in a trivial manner (wrapped in an <h3> or <h2> or something). Do you think I should still be pursuing transclusion as an implementation? My example was set up to try to understand why it evaluates inside the Link function but not Template function.

Comment: If it is super simple, where the directive has no logic of its own, it is just a reusable way to wrap some text in standard markup, then just remove the `scope` parameter and then `return '<h3>' + attrs.text + '</h3>';` or similar in the template function. Or stick to using transclusion and a simple template like: `'<h3 ng-transclude></h3>'`. Both should be fairly equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend GregL's answer, but for completeness:

By its nature, the `template` code has to get run *before* angular compiles your code (obviously, since the template is telling angular what it should compile).  This is why the result is different than what you see in the `link` function, which happens *after* compilation.

If you absolutely must perform manual interpolation, you can use the `$interpolate` service angular provides.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Comment: I can't see how you would use `$interpolate` inside your template function, because you don't have access to the scope at that point, and `$interpolate` gives you a function which takes in a context, such as a scope.

Comment: Whoops, good call Greg!  Yes, the template function doesn't have access to `$scope`, so you have to fake it using something like http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/ .  Definitely try transclusion before that, because you end up having to manually redo a lot of what angular normally gives you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

One way of accessing controller scope from your directive is make the

`scope: false`

read more about directives [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/)

HTH

Comment: Shouldn't I just be able to copy the controller data into the directive's isolated scope and access it throughout my directive via 'text: @text'? My goal is not necessarily to access the controller's scope.

Comment: You can bind u r model like `scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },` , read more in `scope` section in this article http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html